# No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Tags: android

Пытаюсь поменять язык интерфейса с ангилйскомго на Арабский и после применения настроек. У меня NavigationDrawer переезжает в право. При нажатии на NaviDrawer  я получаю такую ошибку. КАК ИСПРАВИТЬ ее?

```
  public void changeLanguageApp(){
    SharedPrefHelper sharedPrefHelper=new SharedPrefHelper(context);
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        conf.setLocale(new Locale( sharedPrefHelper.getUserLanguage() )); // API 17+ only.
    }
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

---

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.riyadbankacademy, PID: 21075
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
                                                                      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1651)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1637)
                                                                      at com.knowledgecity.activity.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:397)
```

---

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryMainApp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:title=" "
            app:theme="@style/AppToolbarTheme">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/colorMainTextWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tool_bar_title_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ma_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/whiteBg" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/ma_load_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header_layout"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        app:theme="@style/MainAppNavigationStyle">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: покажите layout

Comment: Добавил Layout s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В арабском языке все перевёрнуто слева-направо. Для безболезненной поддержки такого гугл ввёл `start/end` параметры везде, где используются `left/right`. С этими значениями лево/право определяются системой в зависимости от локали.

В вашем случае, очевидно, при работе с `DrawerLayout` вы где-то используете что-то с `left`, вместо `start`. Вам надо заменить все `left` на `start` в разметке и коде. Скорее всего достаточно будет в разметке `android:layout_gravity` поменять.